# Biztalk schema pipe delimited header/detail on same level

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have a flat file below. I'm having trouble with the schema with this layout. I switched it around to have a header and a detail and created an application with no problems, but the customer won't change the layout. This is probably pretty basic, but I'm a beginner. How do I take certain fields from this layout and create a header and a detail? The last date field needs to be in the header so you can see how it's random.

PO207730CO|1271|customer 1|john doe|1|161075|161075|BROOM FLAGGED LOBBY|2|5.62|24-Feb-2014|
PO207730CO|1271|customer 1|john doe|2|167316|167316|CLEANER DISPATCH SPRAY HOSPITAL DISINFECTANT W/BLEACH|1|59.84|24-Feb-2014|
PO207730CO|1271|customer 1|john doe|3|162175|162175|DUST PAN LOBBY|2|6.26|24-Feb-2014|
PO207730CO|1271|customer 1|john doe|4|163325|163325|MOP WET LARGE GENERAL-PURPOSE BLUE WB/LP|1|18.45|24-Feb-2014|
PO207730CO|1271|customer 1|john doe|5|164715|164715|SOAP PROVON MEDICATED TFX|1|32.79|24-Feb-2014|
PO207730CO|1271|customer 1|john doe|6|166338|166338|TOWEL MULTI-FOLD SCOTT WHITE|5|18.91|24-Feb-2014|
PO207814CO|1264|customer 2|jane doe|1|Cups||Bib 20x35 2 Ply Lab (756220)|1|17.47|24-Feb-2014|
PO207814CO|1264|customer 2|jane doe|2|Cups||Cup 9oz Translucent (098219)|1|24-Feb-2014|
PO207814CO|1264|customer 2|jane doe|3|Cups||Cup Foam 16oz (177190)|2|35.1|24-Feb-2014|
PO207814CO|1264|customer 2|jane doe|4|Cups||Lid 16/20 Whte Tab W/Sslot (194088)|2|16.57|24-Feb-2014|
PO207814CO|1264|customer 2|jane doe|5|Cups||Tissue 2-Ply 100-Sht (343227)|3|16.38|24-Feb-2014|

Comment: It looks like you have the two Purchase Orders within that file.  Also the 8th line (line 2 of PO207814CO) seems to have a missing pipe and value for the 10th field (value?) and that causes the date to move over one.  Is that correct or a typo?

Comment: There can be multiple POs in the same file. The missing value is fine as well. Is there a way to import this with biztalk, or am I going to have to pre load this in a sql table, then build it the way I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.

I went with an SSIS package to preload a table and build the pipe delimited file. I have Biztalk then picking up that file and debatching it the way I need it.

Comment: You should also consider loading the flat fiee into a table with SSIS, then draining the table by Polling using the WCF SQL Adapter.  It's pretty easy to return hierarchical data from SQL Server that way.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem here is the Flat File Disassembler does not support the concept of splitting/debatching based on changing values, PO207730CO -> PO207814CO for example.

So, you'll have to regroup by PO number at some following step.

You have a few options:

1. Use a Custom XSLT Map to group the lines based on the PO Number,
   then split, by using a Receive Pipeline on an Orchestration for example.
   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17985.xslt-muenchian-grouping-biztalk-complex-transformation.aspx
2. Use an xPath Debatching Pattern in an Orchestration. http://www.biztalkgurus.com/biztalk_server/biztalk_2004/m/biztalk_2004_samples/32438.aspx

Either way, you would parse the flat file as you are now, row by row.

Comment: Thanks for this. Interesting.